# Twitter feed with profile photo

Tags: php, api, twitter

Hello guys I need a bit of help. As I am not very good in PHP I cannot combine two functions that work well separately. 
I found this ready script to display multiple twitter feeds on my page.

```
<?php

// Pull from which accounts? Separated by a space, for example: Username Username Username 
$usernames = "Username Username Username"; 
// Number of tweets to pull in, total. 
$limit = "5"; 
// Show username? 0 = No, 1 = Yes. 
$show = 1;

// REMEBER: When using HTML, escape double-quotations like this: \"

// This comes before the entire block of tweets. 
$prefix = ""; 
// This comes before each tweet on the feed. 
$prefix_sub = ""; 
// This comes after the username but before the tweet content. 
$wedge = ""; 
// This comes after each tweet on the feed. 
$suffix_sub = ""; 
// This comes after the entire block of tweets. 
$suffix = "";

// It is recommended that you do not modify below this point without PHP knowledge.

function parse_feed($usernames, $limit, $show, $prefix_sub, $wedge, $suffix_sub) {

$usernames = str_replace(" ", "+OR+from%3A", $usernames); 
$feed = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3A" . $usernames . "&rpp=" . $limit; 
$feed = file_get_contents($feed); 
$feed = str_replace("&", "&", $feed); 
$feed = str_replace("<", "<", $feed); 
$feed = str_replace(">", ">", $feed); 
$clean = explode("<entry>", $feed); 
$amount = count($clean) - 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {

$entry_close = explode("</entry>", $clean[$i]); 
$clean_content_1 = explode("<content type=\"html\">", $entry_close[0]); 
$clean_content = explode("</content>", $clean_content_1[1]); 
$clean_name_2 = explode("<name>", $entry_close[0]); 
$clean_name_1 = explode("(", $clean_name_2[1]); 
$clean_name = explode(")</name>", $clean_name_1[1]); 
$clean_uri_1 = explode("<uri>", $entry_close[0]); 
$clean_uri = explode("</uri>", $clean_uri_1[1]);

echo $prefix_sub; 
if ($show == 1) { echo "<a href=\"" . $clean_uri[0] . "\">" . $clean_name[0] . "</a>" . $wedge; } 
echo $clean_content[0]; 
echo $suffix_sub;

}

}

echo $prefix; 
parse_feed($usernames, $limit, $show, $prefix_sub, $wedge, $suffix_sub); 
echo $suffix;

// WRITTEN BY RYAN BARR (SPOOKY)! SPOOKYISMY.NAME

?>
```

In order to add the profile photo I created my own function which is very simple:

```
<?php

function display_photo($username, $size='') 
{
    $image_code = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/'. $username;
    return $image_code;

}
<?
```

However I cannot combine the two functions so that I get the username and the twitter feed all together :/
Could you please help me? 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get profile pic in first function:

between lines: `$clean_uri = explode("</uri>", $clean_uri_1[1]);` and `echo $prefix_sub;`
put following code:

```
$profile_image_url_1 = explode('<link type="image/png" href="', $entry_close[0]); 
$profile_image_url = explode('" rel="image"/>', $profile_image_url_1[1]);
$profile_image_url = $profile_image_url[0];

echo $profile_image_url;
```

Comment: Hello izeed! Thanks for the response! 
I did try this but somehow when I run the page what happens is I receive the link instead of the photo. 
For ex.http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1937155026/avatar_cesc_twitter_03_normal.jpg .... and then the tweet
I guess its something with the do with the formatting. Any idea? Thanks a lot for the help you are a lifesaver :))))

Comment: Of course you get link; to show picture use HTML: `<img src='http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1937155026/avatar_cesc_twitter_03_normal.jpg' />`

Comment: yes, I am aware that I need to use HTML. However I wanted the photo to be automatically displayed with the feed. What i get as a result now is some link and then the twitter feed. :/

Comment: Hey sorry, I figured it out :))) Thanks again for the help!